# Laravel eloquent query when filtering

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

im currently working on this query

```
select * 
  from incidents 
 where from_id in (SELECT id FROM users WHERE generalist = 579) 
    or user_id = 579 
 order 
    by(created_at)
```

My User´s model has `id` and a `generalist` column.
My Incident's model has `id`, `user_id` this is the boss id and `from_id` is the employee id

The idea is that `generalist` can see the Incidents, but they may not be in the `user_id` column, so i need to get all the users whose generalist id matches

I try to make it on Eloquent and end up with this //$uid is the user's id

```
$query->whereIn('from_id',User::select('id')->where('generalist',$uid)->get())
            ->orWhere('user_id',$uid);
```

And i get what i want as far i can see, but later on i have an input so i can filter the info //Passed in the $search var

```
$query->where(function($tq) use ($search){
                    $tq->whereHas('from',function($query2) use ($search){
                        $query2->where('firstname', 'like', "%$search%")
                              ->orWhere('lastname', 'like', "%$search%")
                              ->orWhere('number', 'like', "%$search%");
                    })
                    ->orWhere('status', 'like', "%$search%");
                });
```

And this is the "from" function in the model

```
public function from() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\User','id','from_id');
}
```

My problem is that filtering doesn't but when this `$query->where('user_id', $uid);` is running the filter works perfectly.

I dont really get why is not working and if you need more info pls tell me

Comment: May I ask why you are using `$this->hasOne()` in the relationship and not `$this->belongsTo()`? Just from the context it would make sense to me if you had defined `public function incidents() { $this->hasMany('App\Incident', 'incident_id', 'id'); }` on the `User` model, because normally a user can have multiple incidents... But when using `hasMany()`, you need `belongsTo()` on the other end.

Comment: I cant really tell, because i didnt make that part, but why is working in some cases then

Comment: Probably because you are mixing `->where()` and `orWhere()` in a wrong way.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel you mean here `$query->whereIn('from_id',User::select('id')->where('generalist',$uid)->get())
            ->orWhere('user_id',$uid);`

Comment: Yes.. You might need to wrap it into `->where(function($q) {...})` in order to add parentesis to the condition.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem, i change the query but is was because of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if i didnt explain myself well, i solved it adding parentesis with another where function outside

```
          $query->where(function($tq) use ($uid){
                $tq->WhereHas('general',function ($query3) use ($uid){
                    $query3->where('generalist','=',$uid);
                })->orWhere('user_id', $uid);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I find this easier to read...

```
SELECT i.* 
  FROM incidents i
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = i.from_id
 WHERE u.generalist = 579 
    OR i.user_id = 579 
 ORDER 
    BY i.created_at;
```